# need some explanation about recursion?

Tags: java

I still have problem to understand the ancient problem the tower of Hanoi recursion how it really works here. i have read it theoretically but i still don't get how recursion is being called here. Can anybody explain each step what is going on for ex if the value of ring is 2.

In general i know that recursion it calls itself but here i get stuck:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input the number of rings");
    int rings = s.nextInt();
    move(rings, 'A', 'B', 'C');
}

public static void move(int rings, char x, char y, char z){
    if(rings > 0){
        move(rings - 1, x, z, y);
        System.out.println("Move ring " + rings + " from peg " + x + " to " + y + ".");
        move(rings - 1, z, y, x);   
    }
}
```

why when i give to ring value 1 it goes directly to this line:

```
System.out.println("Move ring " + rings + " from peg " + x + " to " + y + ".");
```

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. It will call move(0, 'A', 'C', 'B'), which will do nothing (since it fails your if condition). Then it will proceed to call the output line. Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the value of rings is 1, what happens is the following:

-move method is called with rings = 1
-the condition is met (because 1 > 0 is true) so move is called with rings = 0
-another instance of the move method starts, but this time rings = rings - 1 = 0
-the condition is not met (because 0 > 0 is false) so nothing happens and that method ends
-we're back at the first instance of the method. Now, the System call is executed
-after that, move is called again, with rings = rings - 1 = 0
-another instance of the method starts, and again the condition is not met (0 > 0 is false), so the method is terminated without entering the "if" block

The same will happen if rings equals 2, but a larger and more complex recursive tree will take place. The move method in which rings is 2 will call 2 move methods where rings equals 1, which will themselves call 2 move methods each in which rings is 0.

```
     2
    / \
  1     1
 / \   / \
0   0 0   0
```

Step by step, with rings = 2, this would happen:
-move(1, x, z, y);
-move(0, x, z, y);
-System.out.println("Move ring 1 from peg A to C.");
-move(0, z, y, x);
-System.out.println("Move ring 2 from peg A to B.");
-move(1, z, y, x);
-move(0, x, z, y);
-System.out.println("Move ring 1 from peg C to B.");
-move(0, z, y, x);

The value of rings in each call gives you a hint of where it's happening. For example,
move(1, x, z, y); happens in the method in which rings = 2, because the call is move(rings-1, x, z, y).

I hope this helps.

Comment: in the line 5, how the value of ring is becoming 2? when u say:
syso(move ring 2 from peg A to B)

Comment: Can somebody write the same code in better explonation which i can get to know how recursion in this case is working?

Comment: In line 5, ring is 2 because it happens in an instance of the method where that parameter is 2. Every time a recursive call is made, a new instance of the method "appears" and runs. The method in which the call was made remains there, but is blocked until the new one finishes. Try to make a drawing of all the instances that take place, and then try to link each line of the sequence I wrote with one of the instances.